# Join Select sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to display all of counter of Purchase_Request

Table Purchase_Order

```
counter | qty |      
---------------         
100001  | 10  |  
100001  | 10  |  
100001  | 10  |  
100004  | 30  |
```

Table Purchase_Request

```
counter | total_qty |
---------------------
100001  |     50    |  
100002  |     100   |  
100003  |     50    |  
100004  |     70    |
```

My code only displays 100001 and 100004, I want to display all of counter in purchase_request

```
    select a.counter,
           a.total_qty,
           a.total_qty - b.qty balance 
      from (select counter,
                   sum(total_qty) total_qty
              from purchase_request
          group by counter) a 
inner join (select counter,
                   sum(qty) qty
              from purchase_order 
          group by counter) b 
        on a.counter= b.counter 
  group by a.counter
```

Help?

Comment: Try substituting `inner join` by `left outer join`

Comment: @YourCommonSense sorry I new in sql. BTW thanks for your comment